# Sqlcmd: The -h and the -y 0 options are mutually exclusive?

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

We have an old batch-file (.bat-file) that includes the following sqlcmd code:

```
sqlcmd -S SERVER_NAME -d DB_NAME -I -Q "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName = 'SpecificValue'" -h-1 -k2 -y0
```

This code has been running on a Windows Server 2012 for years without any problems. Now we are migrating to a new server with Windows Server 2016 and the above sqlcmd-code no longer works and returns the message:

```
"Sqlcmd: The -h and the -y 0 options are mutually exclusive."
```

**A couple of questions:**

- Why does this scenario occur on the Windows Server 2016 server and
  not on the Windows Server 2012 server? I’m not able to find any
  documenation or information that the -h and the –y0 options are
  mutually exclusive?
- If the -h and the -y 0 options now are mutually    exclusive, does
  this mean that–y0 officially will suppress a header    the same way
  that –h does? I.e. can we remove the ”-h-1” part of the    code and
  expect the same results with only ”-y0”?

**SQL Server versions the different servers:**

- SQL Server Version on the Windows Server 2012: 11.0.7462.6
- SQL Server Version on the Windows Server 2016: 13.0.52.16.0

Comment: The difference will very likely be the version of `sqlcmd` you are using, not the version of SQL Server. You can find out the version of `sqlcmd` you are using my using the `-?` switch; the second output line gives you the version (for example, I have `Version 14.0.3026.27 NT`). In regards to your second bullet point, have you tried? That would be the easiest way to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the easiest way to find out if only using one of the switches gives the same output is to actually test. I tested this both on Windows (`Version 14.0.3026.27 NT`) and Ubuntu (`Version 17.2.0000.1 Linux`) for completion and got the following results:

Windows:

```
PS Z:\> sqlcmd -S "srvsql2012dev\Sandbox" -E -Q "SELECT 1 AS One;" -h-1 -y0
Sqlcmd: The -h and the -y 0 options are mutually exclusive.
PS Z:\> sqlcmd -S "srvsql2012dev\Sandbox" -E -Q "SELECT 1 AS One;" -h-1
          1

(1 rows affected)
PS Z:\> sqlcmd -S "srvsql2012dev\Sandbox" -E -Q "SELECT 1 AS One;" -y0
1

(1 rows affected)
```

Ubuntu:

```
larnu@qebui:~$ sqlcmd -S "localhost" -U larnu -Q "SELECT 1 AS One;" -h-1 -y0
Sqlcmd: The -h and the -y 0 options are mutually exclusive.
larnu@qebui:~$ sqlcmd -S "localhost" -U larnu -Q "SELECT 1 AS One;" -h-1
Password:
          1

(1 rows affected)
larnu@qebui:~$ sqlcmd -S "localhost" -U larnu -Q "SELECT 1 AS One;" -y0
Password:
1

(1 rows affected)
```

Note that there is a slight difference in the indentation. I don't know what your output looked like before, but i suspect one of these replicates the output you had before.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu for your answer, I tested both options in accordance with your answer and both actually seems to work for us! 

The first one, i.e. to only use ”-h-1”, have the same indentation as our previous output. However, both options still seem to work for us as we in the next step in the code/script use the output value in an if-statement. I.e. the script works as expected and the indentation does not seem to have an affect on this specific scenario.